# How to get Bootstrap's "hero-unit" to fit across the entirety of top section?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am currently learning Rails and CSS, and am trying to replicate the look of Bootstrap's [github page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) as a learning exercise.  Bootstrap's central unit (purpleish colored, and contains the big header "Bootstrap") fits across *all* of the top of the page, having no white space on the side.  However, my current attempt looks more like this [example page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) where the central grey unit containing "hello world" is itself a box, and with white space surrounding it.  Basically, my question is, how would I make that whitespace disappear?  I have attempted to emulate what is shown in the page's source, but am still getting this outcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the source to the example page you posted, you will notice that the hero element is in a `div` called `container`. This class has a left and right margins assigned as well as width. All you need to do is change those to 0 and 100% respectively and you should be well on your way.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the jumbotron and masthead functions in the source for the example you provided

```
<div class="jumbotron masthead">
```